# Script to save depth images using numpy.save instantly crashes Blender, no debug message in console

Tags: python, scripting

I am attempting to save the depth image generated by the 'Z-Pass' as a .npy file to be used outside of Blender.  The following script seems to work perfectly until reaching the line that actually saves the file:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

bpy.ops.render.render()

# get viewer pixels
pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
# size is always width * height * 4 (rgba)
pixels = np.array(pixels)[::4]
print (pixels.shape)

ix = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x
iy = bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y
print (str(ix) + ', ' + str(iy))
depth = np.reshape(pixels, (ix,iy,1))
print(depth.shape)

np.save('C:/tmp/depth.npy', depth)
```

The script succesfully obtains and reshapes the depth image from the Viewer node, but when executing the final line, Blender instantly closes.

I have tried running `blender --debug-all` and there is no information displayed after the script's print statements.

[image: Console when running blender --debug-all]

Any help is appreciated.  I suspect it has to do with Blender running out of memory or perhaps a segmentation fault but I do not know how to  debug it.  Changing the image resolution to use less memory does not seem to fix anything.

Here's the .blend file if anyone wants to try to replicate the issue: [Blender file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49574)

Comment: Blender will only report its own issues, you would want numpy to output some debug info from its save function. The path looks wrong to me - windows use backslash which would be `C:\tmp\depth.npy` you may also want to try `os.path.join('C:', 'tmp', 'depth.npy')` or use only a filename to save in the current dir.

Comment: Thanks but the path is correct.  The file is created in the directory but does not contain any data.

Comment: Runs fine for me (2.79.4 ubuntu 18) after changing path to `/tmp/file.npy` (`/tmp` is standard temp folder on linux)  Is `C:/tmp` your windows temp folder with permissions to write?  Does it not crash if you comment out the numpy save?

Comment: Works fine without the save line.  Changing directories doesn't help either.

Comment: Try creating the file rather than letting numpy create it - `outfile=open('depth.npy', 'w') np.save(outfile, depth)` even try writing something to the file to see if it is numpy or system blocking the write.

Comment: Does wrapping with  [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) shed any light.  Have you tried the numpy save command in system console or idle?

Comment: A clean install of Blender 2.79 has seemed to fix the issue.  Thank you both for your suggestions.